# what is the right ldapsearch version for my linux red-hat machine

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I am little confuse about the following

I want to install the binary **ldapsearch** tool on my linux machine
In order to use this tool to test LDAP connection on my linux ( linux version 5.8 , i386 ) client

So I go for example to this link ( I see there allot of ldapsearch rpm’s ) but not seen version for my linux 5.8 i386

```
      http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ldapsearch&submit=Search+...
```

Can someone advice what is the most suitable tool for my linux machine and and from where I need to download the ldapsearch

Thanks for advice

Comment: "linux version 5.8"? There is no Linux 5.8, they only released 4.1 last week. Did you mean **CentOS** version 5.8?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from that page, `ldapsearch` is in the **`openldap-clients`** package which already is in CentOS & Fedora base repository. Therefore:

```
yum install openldap-clients
```